# It is necessary to catch the load object, component ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to make a drop down menu in the component. Action List depends on the type of object, but the object is not loaded.
Sorry for my English

First, the function is called, then Ajax loading, and it is necessary on the contrary

```js
var set_context_menu = function(model, jqobj) {
    console.log(' node.type:'+model.get('type'));
}

App.CompNodeComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  didInsertElement: function() {
      var node = this.get('node'); // model
      var jqobj = this.$().first(); // jquery object

      if(node.get('isLoaded')){
        set_context_menu(node, jqobj);
      }else{
        // Ember.addObserver(this, 'type', this, set_context_menu(node, jqobj));
        
        // Ember.RSVP.Promise.resolve(node.get('data')).then(function(chartData) {
        //   set_context_menu(chartData, jqobj);
        // });
        
        // Ember.onLoad(node, function() {
        //   node.on('ready', set_context_menu(node, jqobj));
        // });
        
        // Ember.addListener(node, 'load', node, set_context_menu(node, jqobj));

        //node.ready(set_context_menu(node, jqobj));

      }
  },
  

Console:
node.type:undefined
ajax [object Object] // ajax to server from "node"
```

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="template">
    {{#each node in model}}
        {{comp-node node=node}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issues, my data was in a canonical state, I built a function and added an observer on `this.data.isFulfilled`

So maybe try:

```
 dataFulfilled: function() {
      var node = this.get('node'); // model
      var jqobj = this.$().first(); // jquery object

      set_context_menu(node, jqobj);
 }.observes('this.data.isFulfilled'),
```

Comment: Throw a `debugger` in your `didInsertElement` function, log out your node object and paste it in your question so  it can be referenced.